# Error while trying to make an APK

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, dalvik

I am trying to export my code to an APK file, but I am getting this error:

`[2013-10-28 11:29:34 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex:`

`Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex:`

`MEPush] Conversion to Dalvik format failed:`

MEPush is my package name.

I have tried to: 
-refresh and clean my code
-Removed JAR files and added them: package -> properties -> add external JAR's

I am using cordova 2.7.0

Thanks

PS: Don't know if it makes any sense, but here is my folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Struggling all the way around I've gotten one error instead of a lot more, don't know exact how much. But much.

This is the only error I get now:

`[2013-10-28 12:15:17 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;`